# Alternative to CFAbsoluteTimeGetGregorianDate() - 'CFGregorianDate' is deprecated: first deprecated in iOS 8.0

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdate, nscalendar

I recently ran into this deprecation when running Xcode 6.3, targeting iOS 8.3:

> 'CFGregorianDate' is deprecated: first deprecated in iOS 8.0 - Use CFCalendar or NSCalendar API instead

Here's the line of code causing this warning:

```
CFGregorianDate today = CFAbsoluteTimeGetGregorianDate(CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent(), CFTimeZoneCopySystem())
```

I'm doing a bit of research, but I haven't been able to find a way to do it using the `CFCalendar` API. The `NSCalendar` API is pretty much straightforward (even using `[NSDate date]`), but I'd like something more lightweight if possible.

Anybody have some suggestions?

Comment: There is nothing more lightweight than [NSDate date].

Comment: @gnasher729 My end goal is to get the `day` of the date, which I've been using `NSDateComponents` for. Is there any better way to do this?

Comment: Just use NSDateComponents. Choosing CF over NS for date calculation is almost certainly a premature optimization, and is unlikely to confer any substantive performance benefits.

Comment: Thanks, @mattt, I appreciate the explanation.